# How to check string if in_array using file() or other method except file_get_contents()?

Tags: php, arrays, file-get-contents

I want to check if a value/string exists in an array (or an file). I've tried to find a solution from anywhere but I do not get it.

Assume I have a file `file.tpl`:

> a1 a2 a3 b1 b2 b3 c1 c2 c3...

I can resolve it using `file_get_contents` and `strpos` method:

```
$content = file_get_contents("file.tpl");
if (strpos($content, "a2") !== false) 
{ 
    echo "Match found<br>"; 
}
```

But my problem is this file is denied from direct access by `.htaccess`, so I can't use `file_get_contents` method.

```
# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

If I use `file_get_contents` method it displays error like this:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(bla..bla..bla..) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/user/public_html/mysite.com/dir/file.tpl on line 3
```

I tried using the `file()` method to split it into an array and I try to find using `in_array` method, but I do not understand how to apply it.

Maybe like this:

```
$content_array = file("file.tpl");
if (in_array("a2", $content_array)) 
{
    echo "Match found<br>"; 
}
```

Comment: so is the problem that you cannot get the file in the first place in order to then parse into an array to check of can you actually GET the file values its the next bit thats tricky?

Comment: `htaccess` does **not** and will **never** limit PHP from reading the file (unless it's on a different server) - it disables *Apache* of ever serving the file. PHP =/= Apache. If you can't read the file it's your file permissions that have a problem - not your webserver/code.

Comment: There might be a permissions problem, but in the case of a local file and PHP, `.htaccess` is irrelevant. What does `file_get_contents()` return? Try `var_dump(file_get_contents());` - does it return `false`? If so, then the call indeed fails, but for any number of reasons.

Comment: Thanks guys for your answer, It is resolved by @voodoo417 method:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$content_array = file("file.tpl");
if (strpos(implode(' ',$content_array), "a2")) 
{
  echo "Match found<br>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
$content = file_get_contents("file.tpl");
$striping = explode(" ", $content);
foreach($striping as $strip) 
{ 
    if($strip == 'a2')
    {
        echo "Match found<br />";
    }
}
```

Don't forget it's `<br />` same as in `<hr />` you open it and you close it in the same time.

Comment: It says: `Warning: file_get_contents(bla bla..) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/user/public_html/site.com/dir/file.tpl on line 3..` My .htaccess is like this `# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>` Maybe this .htaccess setting that make `file_get_contetns()` method doesn't work.

Comment: Try to change file_get_contents to file. And if you change the file don't use / to go back to the root.